# How to create an object from a class path/name using Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, oop, reflection

I've got an object 'Foo Action' which is of type `FooProcess` (interface) [null object].
I want to initialize 'Foo Action' as an object of a subclass [`FooOne` or `FooTwo`] of `FooProcess`.

Using the Spring Framework, I am able to create `ArrayList` `FooList` (a list of names of subclasses of `FooProcess`), now I would like to initialize `FooAction` as one of the subclasses. (Given a parameter `selected` to define which class I want it to initialize as)

All subclasses of `FooProcess` have a constructor which accepts a `String`.

My problem is specifically on this line

```
    FooAction = component.getClass().getConstructor(f);
```

Full Method:

```
public FooProcess Load(String selected, String f) throws ClassCastException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException{
    ArrayList<String> FooList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(true);
    provider.addIncludeFilter(new AssignableTypeFilter(FooProcess.class));
    for (BeanDefinition component : provider.findCandidateComponents("org.project.foomodule.systems")) {
        if(selected == component.getBeanClassName()){
        FooAction = component.getClass().getConstructor(f);
    } }
    return FooAction;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the Spring Bean Factory to instantiate objects and inject dependencies?

Comment: @skaffman The 'problem' I hinted in the post does not give me what I need, moreover the IDE says that it is syntactically wrong.

Comment: Why don't you use `FooAction action = context.getBean(Class.forName(selected));` on Spring's ApplicationContext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this, it works the same

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class SampleInstance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Rectangle rectangle;
        Class rectangleDefinition;
        Class[] intArgsClass = new Class[] { int.class, int.class };
        Integer height = new Integer(12);
        Integer width = new Integer(34);
        Object[] intArgs = new Object[] { height, width };
        Constructor intArgsConstructor;

        try {
            rectangleDefinition = Class.forName("java.awt.Rectangle");
            intArgsConstructor = rectangleDefinition
                    .getConstructor(intArgsClass);
            rectangle = (Rectangle) createObject(intArgsConstructor, intArgs);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static Object createObject(Constructor constructor,
            Object[] arguments) {

        System.out.println("Constructor: " + constructor.toString());
        Object object = null;

        try {
            object = constructor.newInstance(arguments);
            System.out.println("Object: " + object.toString());
            return object;
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return object;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see: you're calling getClass() on the BeanDefinition, which will be the BeanDefinition class itself, not the class of the defined Bean.

Also, you shouldn't compare strings with == in Java. Use .equals() instead.